# How can I find the recursive remainder in prolog (without arithmetic)

Tags: prolog

How can I find the recursive remainder in prolog (without arithmetic). Here is the question:

`remainder(X,Y,R)` to be true if `X` divided by `Y` leaves a remainder of `R`

Comment: What do you mean by `recursive` in recursive remainder?

Comment: If you are using SWI-Prolog, then see [Rational number examples](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=rational)

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "recursive remainder" and you need to show what you've tried and ask a more specific question.